# How can you specify the file name for a Log4net SmtpPickupDirAppender?

Tags: log4net

By default the SmtpPickupDirAppender appender creates a file without an extension.  I can't find that there is a parameter (or other option) to configure the file extension.

The email service that picks up the file from the directory specified in the "pickupDir" parameter requires a file extension.

Is there a way to specify one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not built in.

From the source, it looks like it just creates a file name based on a guid and doesn't offer any configuration options,

```
  filePath = Path.Combine(m_pickupDir, SystemInfo.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
  writer = File.CreateText(filePath);
```

However, if you pull the source, it should be relatively straight forward to create your own appender that adds an file extension.